# Crystal Reports - Suppressed header in Landscape orientation but still there is space on page top

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a report using crystal report in which i have suppressed the header. Orientation of page is Landscape but when i print the page there is space in top area of page. I don't know why this space is coming.any help?

[image]

Print snapshot is below

[image]

Comment: which header is supressed?

Comment: page header of report

Answer (score 0):

Check list:

- Report header supressed
- Margin top sets to 0